# deployment single ejb module with dependencies in netbeans and glassfish

Tags: maven, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

In NB 7.2 i have ejb module managed by maven with several dependencies. I try to run it on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 but it seems like server doesn't resolve libraries on classpath. I think arguments in deploy command ("deploy?DEFAULT=..." - i'm not sure it is command) are correct - there are all libraries in this command, but during creating ejb server throws class not found exception - although this class is in library in deploy command.

It is possible to deploy single EJB module with dependencies without enterprise application?

Thanks for advice

Comment: The EJB module is a simple jar archive which does not contain any library / dependency. I prefer to archive it as an EAR instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of mechanisms for deploying EJBs. If the EJB has dependencies and is used in a web application, check if it can be used in the EJB lite configuration. It is easiest to deploy it in a WAR file along with a web application. There is an article [Introducing the Java EE 6 Platform: Part 3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/javaee6overview-part3-139660.html) that details a number of the specifics.

Alternatively, you may deploy it as part of an EAR file which will include the dependencies.

If the EJB must be used as a standalone EJB, the dependencies must be be in the server classpath, or repackaged in the EJB jar file. NetBeans 7.2.1 can do that for you.

Comment: How do I configure NetBeans to do that?